# Calculates sum for nested map with lambdas in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have nested map:

```
Map<String,Map<Integer,List<MyObject>>> myMap;
```

MyObject has field "**field1**".

How to calculate total sum of **field1** for all objects in each List USING lambda in Java?

Comment: have you tried anything? Your IDE should be able to assist you perfectly trying to iterate over the different collections.

Comment: You could easily do this imperatively too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a stream over the map values, then flatten consecutively and extract the field to sum then finally invoke the `sum` terminal operation.

```
int summation = myMap.values()
                     .stream()
                     .map(Map::values)
                     .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                     .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                     .mapToInt(MyObject::getField1)
                     .sum();
```

Comment: You could use `.values()` instead of `.entrySet()`

Comment: or `myMap.values().stream().flatMap(m -> m.values().stream())
                .flatMap(l -> l.stream()).mapToInt(MyObject::getField1).sum();`

Answer (score 0):

try this

`myMap.forEach((k,v)->{v.values().stream().forEach(w->{field1 += field1;});});
return field1;`